# Android: isDirectory() always returning true

Tags: java, android

I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666093/android-file-isdirectory-always-returning-true-for-a-file-so-unable-to-add), but it did not help.

My filename filter to get directories and .txt files only:

```
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter()
{
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
    {
        if (dir.isDirectory())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return dir.getName().endsWith(".txt");
        }
    }
};
```

I also tried !dir.isFile()

Applying the filter to the list of files and directories:

```
            CurDir = homeDir;
            dir = new File(homeDir);
            values = dir.list(filter);
            if (values == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Files/Folders", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

Value of homeDir:

```
homeDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

It still shows .png and all other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `File dir` passed is the directory containing the actual file, so it will always be a directory. The full file you have is %dir%/%name%. I believe name will be "/" or perhaps null if the overall file is a directory though.

You could also create the full file by doing `new File(dir, name);`

Comment: No because when it loads it shows the root of the sd like I intended it to.

Comment: Do some logging; log the dir and the name and check

Comment: I looked at the console tab and logcat and everywhere else in eclipse system.out.println doesnt work with android apps

Comment: FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter()
 {
  public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
        {
   File tmp = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name);
   if (tmp.isDirectory())
   {
    Log.i("Folder: ", tmp.getAbsolutePath());
    return true;
   }
   else
   {
    Log.i("File: ", tmp.getAbsolutePath());
    return name.endsWith(".txt");
   }
        }
 };