# Android - Configurable directory?

Tags: android, android-intent

One of the steps in building my app is to let the user select a folder in which some files are stored. How can i make this configurable, without hardcoding the directory. Is there any 3rd party library that i can use to do this ?

Comment: This should give you a few options: [Choose File Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592717/choose-file-dialog). You can also implement this on your own. It is quite straight-forward.

Comment: That dialog is so cool I tweaked it so you could use it as a mini file explorer. Gonna post the code in a bit, need to refactor it first. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Vikram's link provides a dialog that you can use. You can then save the directory the user chose using  [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) is a simple example on how to use Shared Preferences.

Another tutorial can be found [here](http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.com/2013/01/sharedpreference-in-android.html).

**UPDATE:** A switch suddenly turned on inside me to do something like this. Credits still go to schwiz in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3645048/2431281) for the base code used. :)

```
//global variables
private File[] fileList;
private String[] filenameList;

private File[] loadFileList(String directory) {
    File path = new File(directory);

    if(path.exists()) {
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                //add some filters here, for now return true to see all files
                //File file = new File(dir, filename);
                //return filename.contains(".txt") || file.isDirectory();
                return true;
            }
        };

        //if null return an empty array instead
        File[] list = path.listFiles(filter);
        return list == null ? new File[0] : list;
    } else {
        return new File[0];
    }
}

public void showFileListDialog(final String directory, final Context context) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(context);

    File[] tempFileList = loadFileList(directory);

    //if directory is root, no need to up one directory
    if(directory.equals("/")) {
        fileList = new File[tempFileList.length];
        filenameList = new String[tempFileList.length];

        //iterate over tempFileList
        for(int i = 0; i < tempFileList.length; i++) {
            fileList[i] = tempFileList[i];
            filenameList[i] = tempFileList[i].getName();
        }
    } else {
        fileList = new File[tempFileList.length+1];
        filenameList = new String[tempFileList.length+1];

        //add an "up" option as first item
        fileList[0] = new File(upOneDirectory(directory));
        filenameList[0] = "..";

        //iterate over tempFileList
        for(int i = 0; i < tempFileList.length; i++) {
            fileList[i+1] = tempFileList[i];
            filenameList[i+1] = tempFileList[i].getName();
        }
    }

    builder.setTitle("Choose your file: " + directory);

    builder.setItems(filenameList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            File chosenFile = fileList[which];

            if(chosenFile.isDirectory()) {
                showFileListDialog(chosenFile.getAbsolutePath(), context);
            }
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

public String upOneDirectory(String directory) {
    String[] dirs = directory.split(File.separator);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");

    for(int i = 0; i < dirs.length-1; i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(dirs[i]).append(File.separator);
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

The code above acts like a mini file explorer that lists the files and folders of the Android File System. You use it like:

```
showFileListDialog(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(),
    MainActivity.this);
```

Answering your question:
Add global key variables

```
//package name goes here.
public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.example.app"; 
public static final String KEY_DIRECTORY_SELECTED = 
    PACKAGE_NAME + ".DIRECTORY_SELECTED";

private SharedPreferences prefs;
```

initialize your SharedPreferences somewhere on onCreate before you use it:

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences(PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and then you can add a positive button to the dialog

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Save Directory", new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        prefs.edit().putString(KEY_DIRECTORY_SELECTED, directory).commit();
    }
});
```

In your activity, instead of using the SDCard default directory you can

```
//if no saved directory yet, use SDCard directory as default
String oldChosenDirectory = prefs.getString(KEY_DIRECTORY_SELECTED,
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
showFileListDialog(oldChosenDirectory, MainActivity.this);
```

As Vikram pointed out. you also need to do this in your FileNameFilter so that the dialog will display directories ONLY.

Update: As noted in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12700444/2431281), the parameters `dir` and `filename` does not refer to the same file. The `dir` parameter is the directory containing the file, while `filename` is the filename of the file itself. To determine whether the filte itself is a directory, we need to create a new file from the parameters like so:

```
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + filename);
        return file.isDirectory();
    }
};
```

Comment: Excellent post. +1. One issue: The OP wants `to let the user select a folder`. So, `FilenameFilter.accept()` should be returning `file.isDirectory()`.