# How to properly pass function parameters?

Tags: java, arrays, function

Currently I have the code like below:

```
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        ...
        return filename.contains(".png") || filename.contains(".jpg") || file.isDirectory();
```

(the full code can be found there - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18523047/604388)

So, `.png` and `.jpg` are hardcoded now. I would like to make it as function parameter(s) and allow to pass several extensions, not just one. How could I do it?

I think I can pass list of extensions as array, but how could I perform all these checks (`filename.contains()`) for all array elements?

Comment: Given to pass the list of extensions as an array, as you suggest, is there a reason why the simple approach, to iterate over the array, wouldnt work?

Comment: @LA_ Please put the real code. You cannot embedd one method in another only if you do it by declaring it into an anonymus class. Is this the case?

Comment: @loan, I've added the link to the full code and edited the initial code to avoid the confusion. Sorry for having wrong code before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below snippet which should be enough for your needs :

```
private boolean loadFileList(String directory, String...extensions){
    for (String extension : extensions){
        if (filename.contains(extension))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**P.S.** I'm not sure what is the `filename` type, but if returns `boolean` then the above example should fit

Comment: Pretty sure `true` does not match the type `file[]`

Comment: Really ? Well I copied his method signature from the question. As long the question doesn't have any downvote, I cannot understand why you downvoted me.

Comment: @Eric: I agree with loan, it is the OP that made a mistake in his return type. If it is the reason of the doynvote on his answer and/or mine, I think you are mistaken

Comment: @Eric feel better you downvoted one question and two answers ? You should have a look at other answers too.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach I can come up with is to iterate through array of extensions:

```
boolean res = false;
for (String ext: extensions) {
    if (filename.endsWith(ext)) {
        res = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: .contains() is not proper way to check extension, you can check with .endsWith() method

Answer (score 1):

No built-in answer here I fear, so iterate will be the good old solution:

```
boolean result = false;
for (String extension : extensions) {
    if (filename.contains(extension)) {
        result = true;
        break;
    }
}
return result || file.isDirectory();
```

`extensions` may be a `String[]` or a `Collection<String>`

Note : Better, yet, to use endsWith() rather than contains() for extensions. But I used the same condition as OP...

Comment: .contains is not proper method to check for extension.

Comment: I agree but it is not the point. He wanted to know how to handle his parameters, and he used contains(). With endsWith() it is more correct, but functionnally different.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using an `enum` to avoid hardcoding.-

```
public enum Extension {
    PNG     (".png"),
    JPG     (".jpg");

    private String suffix;

    Extension(String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    public String getSuffix() {
        return suffix;
    }
}
```

Your code would look like this.-

```
public boolean accept(File dir, String filename, Extension... extensions) {
    boolean res = file.isDirectory();

    if (!res) {
        for (int i = 0; i < extensions.length; i ++) {
            res = res || filename.contains(extensions[i].getSuffix());
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: What does this enum offer over the strings?

Comment: Your function has to return `File[]` whilst it returns `boolean` value.

Comment: Well, it keeps the hardcode values "under control", so that the rest of application can safely call the enum types.

Comment: Thanks, @ssantos. I've edited the question, there is no problem with returning `boolean` - I haven't copied the full code initially.

Comment: Ok, just edited my answer, I guess that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;

public class NewClass {
    public static File[] loadFileList(String dir, FileFilter filter){
        return new File(dir).listFiles(filter);
    }

    public static void loadFiles(){
        File files[] = loadFileList("c:\\", new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                if(pathname.getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")){
                    return true;
                }
                if(pathname.getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        // here do some DIRTY things with files....
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't answer the question. Your extensions are not parameters, they are still hardcoded.

Comment: Thats is what I am doing, passing parameters as FileFilter... then no need to hardcode anything in loadFileList method...